# How to transform number on a link when i can get this information

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. This extension make easier send massages 
 throughout whats App, I get it and it is working.

But now i want to improve it, letting the user just click on the number on the page and sending a message.

My need is: turn the normal number on pages as a link when the user click on it the form will fill it automatically.

This page is not mine.

https://github.com/roddyka/Message-to-Whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a content script that searches for phone numbers in the DOM text nodes  (through a regex for example) and update them.

The simplest approach is to run it once (when the DOM is loaded) however this won't work perfectly as your page DOM isn't necessarily ready when your content script DOM is.

Also, 90% pages update the DOM dynamically. So you should either listen for DOM changes or use an interval to run your script again.

Comment: But how to do that?

Comment: What's the part you're stuck with?